# How to select the value in option if option value has slash

Tags: javascript

HTML select code

```
<select name="about" class="form-control radius0 clear-value" 
   id="aboutus" 
   onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && 
   (window.location = 
   this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
   <option value="aims-objective">AIMS &amp; OBJECTIVES</option>
   <option value="history">HISTORY</option>
   <option value="our-supporters">OUR SUPPORTERS</option>
   <option value="donate-now">DONATE NOW</option>
</select>
```

If option values are like this it picks up the value and shows in the dropdown. But now the option value is changed to

```
<option value="/about-us/aims-objective">AIMS &amp; OBJECTIVES</option>
<option value="/about-us/history">HISTORY</option>
<option value="/about-us/our-supporters">OUR SUPPORTERS</option>
<option value="/about-us/donate-now">DONATE NOW</option>
```

FUNCTION

```
$(function(){ // Makes current value as default one
  var selectedValue = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  console.log(selectedValue);
  $("#aboutus").val(selectedValue);
})
```

It doesn't work now. What are the possible changes to be made in the onchange function. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Share you `onchange` function as well.

Comment: @FarhanTahir he did share the function, is coded inline

Comment: My bad just saw it. Thanks.

Comment: It works fine for me? https://jsfiddle.net/qpkdLmqt/

Comment: @monisha , I pretty sure it not the option with a slash are causing the problem, maybe is the url value causing it, try `value="./about-us/history"`

Comment: See my fiddle, it works fine...

Comment: http://abc.test/about-us/history This is the URL. This $("#aboutus").val(selectedValue); takes value from URL. But when the value is /about-us/history  the dropdown is blank once selected

Comment: @monisha, will that `abc.test/` is going to chnage? or it ll be same?

Comment: @Sravan abc.test/ will remain the same..abc.test is site url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my answer, I assume you are in `abc.test/about-us/history` page and run the code and check, the `HISTORY` will be `preselected`.

Since the `site url` is not going to change you can follow this solution.

```js
// script to chnage the dropdown

function selectChange(select){ 
var selectedValue; 
if(select != undefined){ 
selectedValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value; 

selectedValue = '/about-us/' + selectedValue; 
select.options[select.selectedIndex].value = selectedValue; 
$("#aboutus").val(selectedValue); 
window.location = selectedValue; 
} 
else{ 
selectedValue = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); 
} 
console.log(selectedValue); 
$("#aboutus").val(selectedValue); 
} 

selectChange(); 

// script to pre select the dropdown

$(function(){ 
console.log(window.location.href); 
var selectedValue = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); 
console.log(selectedValue); 
$("#aboutus").val(selectedValue); 
})
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 desktop styled-select"> 
<select name="about" class="form-control radius0 clear-value" id="aboutus" onchange="selectChange(this)"> 
<option value="aims-objective">AIMS &amp; OBJECTIVES</option> 
<option value="history">HISTORY</option> 
</select> 
</div>
```

[**Here is a Working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/22PslCcsTrhIiDerm4gg?p=preview)

Comment: @monisha, please check my answer and tell me if you need any change

Comment: There's a site abc.test and when it comes to abc.test/about-us   There is a dropdown and that dropdown changes the URL and goes to other page like if history is selected history page is seen and URL changes to abc.test/about-us/aims-objective and the select value is AIMS $amp; OBJECTIVES

Comment: the script you added loads for everypage?

Comment: can you send the result of `console.log(selectedValue);`

Comment: our-supporters,history,donate-now..Whichever is selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170201/discussion-between-sravan-and-monisha).